# Remove default "Python" submenu with Tkinter Menu on Mac OSX

Tags: python, macos, menu, tkinter

When creating a Menu in Tkinter on Mac OSX, the very first submenu is labeled "Python".  Is there a way to remove this so that the only submenus are the ones that I have created or does that submenu always exist no matter what?

Here is how I'm creating my menu

```
root = self.winfo_toplevel()
self.menu = Menu(root)
root['menu'] = self.menu
self.sub_menu = Menu(self.menu)
self.menu.add_cascade(label='My Program', menu=self.sub_menu)
self.sub_menu.add_command(label='Quit', command=self.quit)
```

Comment: Version of Python and TKinter? OS shouldn't affect it afaik.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way I've been able to rename the first Menu title is to compile the python to an application.  I did this using [py2app](https://py2app.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

I have an example app you can see here:

https://bitbucket.org/jgrigonis/mathfacts/overview

The key code is in this file:

https://bitbucket.org/jgrigonis/mathfacts/src/b994b6225743/setupmac.py

Comment: Great! I didn't know about py2app. Thank you!