# Where to define the about box in a OSx app

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, tkinter

I created an application using Python 3.4 using tkinter.  I'm using Py2App to create my .app file for deployment.  All is working fine except I can't figure out how to get an about box to display from the top menu on the Mac.  There is one that is coming from somewhere but it is about Tcl & Tk.  I'm fine with leaving that one but I'd like my own to show as well.  Here is the screenshot.  I do have two tkinter menu widgets in my python app but they don't show anywhere either.

[image]

Comment: I know I managed this at some point by looking at the module `idlelib.macosxSupport`, it has quite the setup to `overrideRootMenu`, If I can remind myself how to accomplish it _without_ monkey patching idlelib and cherry picking the necessary functions,  I'll post the answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove default "Python" submenu with Tkinter Menu on Mac OSX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8695926/remove-default-python-submenu-with-tkinter-menu-on-mac-osx)

Comment: But I **know** it is possible otherwise because I use IDLE and it manages it... somehow...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define a command `tkAboutDialog` to override the default About dialog that's shown by the Tk framework (and hence Python's Tk bindings).

You can do this as follows:

```
root.createcommand('tkAboutDialog', about_dialog)
```

Where `root` is the `Tk` object and `about_dialog` is a Python function that shows the about dialog.

For more information on OSX specific features of the Tk library see: http://tcl.tk/software/mac/features.tml

Comment: Worked like a charm. I would have never figured that out by reading the docs you pointed to but simply adding that line of code and creating a simple def about_dialog(): function did the trick.